# Integrating Spring JpaRepository into JAR-RS (jersey) application generating java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jparepository

#Introduction
I have a JAX-RS application using the JERSEY implementation. The container I am using is Wildfly 31.

I am working with Eclipse JPA implementation. I have introduced Springs JpaRepository to take advantage of some of their APIs but I keep on getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to access it.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Controller Class  `SecurityController.java`

```
package com.example.backend.controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.example.backend.core.jwt.APIResponse;
import com.example.backend.core.jwt.anotations.CORSAllow;
import com.example.backend.models.entity.TlRole;
import com.example.backend.models.repository.TlRoleRepository;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@CORSAllow
@Path("/roles")
public class SecurityController {

    @Autowired
    private TlRoleRepository tlRoleRepository;


    @GET
    public Response index() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return (new APIResponse(true, null, tlRoleRepository.findAll())).res().build();
    }
}
```

JpaRepository Class

```
package com.example.backend.models.repository;

import com.example.backend.models.entity.TlRole;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TlRoleRepository extends JpaRepository<TlRole, Integer> {
}
```

Application Class

```
package com.example.backend;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationEntry extends Application {
}
```

Entity Class

```
package com.example.backend.models.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class TlRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
...

}
```

This is the error I get when I try to hit the endpoint
Error Log

```
14:38:55,459 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.DefaultExceptionMapper] (default task-1) RESTEASY002375: Error processing request GET /backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/roles - com.example.backend.controllers.SecurityController.index: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.backend.models.repository.TlRoleRepository.findAll()" because "this.tlRoleRepository" is null
    at deployment.backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.example.backend.controllers.SecurityController.index(SecurityController.java:31)
    at deployment.backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.example.backend.controllers.SecurityController$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.index(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.example.backend.controllers.SecurityController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.index(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:70)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:44)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.12.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Comment: This feels like the hardest possible way to implement.  Wildfly has JAX-RS and JPA built in.  Springboot has similar capabilities.  Why are you trying to push the two together?  Personally I would go to a Wildfly only solution, using JAX-RS and JPA standards.  But, either way, merging the two together is going to be a challenge.

Comment: I wanted to use some of JapRepository's out-of-the-box APIs. Like the way they do pagination. however, if all else fails I would go with the JAX-RS and JPA standards rout

Comment: So finally I used raw JAX-RS and JPA standards. It was easy in the long run and also ported the application to Helidon 4. Running in production now and the speed of Helidon is great. Powered by their virtual threads.

Comment: Nicely done!  I hadn't heard of Helidon but it looks very interesting.